# Phase angle of sine wave (confusion)

Tags: ac, phasor

Usually, phasors are represented by Acos(ωt + φ) where φ is the phase angle.
Using this convention, we need to convert sin(ωt) into cos(ωt - 90) to get its phase angle [like this thumbnail on a YouTube video](https://www.google.com/search?q=phasor%20form%20of%20sinusoid%20wave&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhxqjZooDxAhXYzDgGHfFeDo0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1536&bih=722&dpr=1.25#imgrc=EftdcN6ZZKL3sM).

**But in EE, the AC sources are usually sinusoids and back when I first studied about phasors in physics, they were introduced as Asin(ωt + φ) with *φ being the phase angle*.**

What is the correct way to represent sine waves *(say 120sin(120πt))* in polar form?

Comment: I don't see that there is a best way; either or one might be more applicable to a particular problem.

Comment: So there is no particular "convention"?

Comment: There might be for some applications but you mention no applications.

Comment: Say V = 120sin(120πt) Volts then according to EE convention it should be 120, angle(-90 degrees) ?

Comment: There is no *one, common* convention. So even in the above comment example, it is ambiguous. To avoid ambiguity, always specify the reference phasor at the beginning itself.

Comment: \$V = 123\cdot\sin(120πt)\$ is a 123 volt peak amplitude sinewave of frequency 60 Hz with zero phase angle offset when t = 0

Answer (score 2):

All that matters is the phase difference. There is no absolute phase angle. It's just like voltage -- it's always measured relative to something you pick as a reference.

> But in EE, the AC sources are usually sinusoids and back when I first studied about phasors in Physics, they were introduced as Asin(wt + phi) with phi being the phase angle.

They were just saying that sin(wt+phi) has a phase angle of phi with respect to sin(wt).

It's ok to represent sinusoid waveforms with either sin() or cos(). When speaking of phase angle just pick a a form that represents a phase angle of 0 and stick to it.